# Storing string containing double quote in Liferay preferences

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

I'm storing preferences in a Liferay 6.1 config page as seen below without any problem

```
prefs.setValue(prefName, request.getParameter(prefName));
prefs.store();
```

Then I can retrieve them like this

```
prefs.getValue(prefName, StringPool.BLANK);
```

This is working fine when the string being stored doesn't contain double quotes but when it does the part of the string after the quote gets "cut off".
I presume it's some url encoding/decoding issue and I'm not sure how to get around it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me. Do you happen to use the preferences in an input field? In this case you'll obviously have to escape the preferences. Imagine this scenario: Let the value for your preferences be `test"test`. Now use them in an input field like this:

```
<input type="text" value="<%=prefs%>"/>
```

This will result in illegal HTML like this

```
<input type="text value="test"test"/>
```

And the browser will naturally only show test as value - as the attribute is terminated with the resulting quote. Luckily Liferay has `com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.HtmlUtil` which you can utilize, e.g. try

```
<input type="text" value="<%=HtmlUtil.escapeAttribute(prefs)%>"/>
```

This will generate HTML like this:

```
<input type="text" value="test&#x22;test"/>
```

which is well parsable and gives the expected result. And while you're at it, check the other escape methods that you find in HtmlUtil.

If this doesn't solve your problem, please give the version number you're using.